# Bad operand for binary operator?

Tags: java, if-statement, binary, operands

I have no idea what is wrong, I am a beginner. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

`if(room.contains((targetRoom1) || (targetRoom2) && targetDay)){`

The error for this code is bad operand types for binary operator '`&&`'
first type: `java.lang.String`; second type: `java.lang.String`

Comment: I'm not a Java Developer, but in the languages I know the 2nd `)` before the end of the line should go after targetRoom2... like so:

`if(room.contains((targetRoom1) || (targetRoom2)) && targetDay)) {`

Comment: Please add more of your code.  How are these variables declared?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that *targetRoom2* and *targetDay* are not booleans, so you cannot use *&&*.

I guess you want to test something like:

```
if(room.contains(targetRoom1) || room.contains(targetRoom2) && (targetDay == queryDay)){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(room.contains(targetRoom1) || room.contains(targetRoom2) && targetDay!=null){
```

This should work